# static stylesheet with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, assets

I am new on developing, so please be patiente :)

I decide to design my site with jetstrap (visual designer for bootstrap), download the html and then programming the back-end with python and upload it to google app engine.

When I download the files from jetstrap, I have a folder with my html and a folder named assets with 3 folders inside. CSS, images, js.

If I open the html with a browser, I can see the site like I design it. But if I render it with python and open it on localhost, I see it without any css.

I try to add the folder to app.yamal

```
application: web-development-test
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /templates/assets
  static_dir: stylesheet


- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

templates is the folder on my application dir with all my htmls and assets the folder with css, js and images.

A part of html from jetstrap is:

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body { padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way
      to the bottom of the topbar */ }
    </style>
```

I see the rel=stylesheet there, that's why I add on app.yamal the static_dir: stylesheet

Almost everything I have done, are from online tutorials.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:
The whole structure of my app folder

```
google project
    app.yaml
    favicon.ico
    index.yaml
    main.py
    templates
        page1.html
        page2.html
        assets
           css
           img
           js
```

Comment: Can you post more details about your directory structure? What directories are in the top level of your project, next down, etc? You might also find the docs on [static directory handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers) helpful.

Comment: I edit the first post with my directory structure. I will also see the doc you gave me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first handler in your app.yaml says "make the directory stylesheets (to be found in the app root) available at the URL path /templates/assets." This is probably the reverse of what you want. Try this handler instead:

```
- url: /assets
  static_dir: templates/assets
```

That will make it so that, for example, `http://localhost:8090/assets/css/bootstrap.css` returns the file at `templates/assets/css/bootstrap.css`. Assuming page1.html is served at `/` or `/page1` or similar, that should do what you want.

Comment: Really really thank you. This solve my problem. As I said I am new on this and your comment not only solve it, but make me understand what I made wrong.

Comment: @Tasos I'm glad I could help. It's proper StackOverflow etiquette to accept answers that solve your problem (by clicking the arrow on the left of them), which also encourages other people to answer your future questions. (You might want to go back to your previous questions and accept answers there, too.)

Answer (score 2):

The order of handler might cause the problems:

url: /stylesheets static_dir: stylesheets
url: /.* script: helloworld.application

will work instead of

url: /.* script: helloworld.application
url: /stylesheets static_dir: stylesheets

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I followed everything to the latter even the indentation error in the app.yaml file as can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/py101_2/lesson4).
I fixed the indentation and that was it.